# Unit testing QueueRuntimeInfo

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

I'm trying to write unit tests around Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and need to return a mock instance of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management.QueueRuntimeInfo in my tests. QueueRuntimeInfo has an internal constructor which takes a string as a parameter. So any attempt with Moq or in code to instantiate gets QueueRuntimeInfo does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Cannot access internal constructor of QueueRuntimeInfo here.

Read numerous articles including: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqInternals.aspx and http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpFriendAssembly.aspx

But not sure if this the correct way to go and being honest not 100% sure of how to put/reference InternalsVisibleTo in my unit test which is in a .net core 2.2 solution.

Is it possible to be able to create an instance of this in my unit tests please?

Comment: You would decorate the code you're testing with the `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute.  It doesn't go in your unit test.

Comment: Can you please post the snippet that you try to test? E.g. how do you receive the QueueRuntimeInfo? If you can mock the thing that returns you the QueueRuntimeInfo it's as simple as making a class that derives from QueueRuntimeInfo and then you'd return that class.

Comment: You can't in inherit from QueueRuntimeInfo because its constructor is internal.

Comment: I can't decorate the code I'm testing as it is part of the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus assembly